# Convert Weekly Data to Hourly Data in Dataframe with Repeating Column Names

Tags: pandas, sorting, repeat, tile

I have data that looks like this in a 52 x 5 df:

```
    week    SITE    LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL    SITE    LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL
0   1   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1.0
1   2   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1.0
2   3   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1.0
3   4   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1.0
4   5   BARTON CHAPEL   1.1 PENASCAL I  1.0
5   6   BARTON CHAPEL   1.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
6   7   BARTON CHAPEL   1.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
7   8   BARTON CHAPEL   1.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
8   9   BARTON CHAPEL   1.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
9   10  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
10  11  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
11  12  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
12  13  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
13  14  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
14  15  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
15  16  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
16  17  BARTON CHAPEL   2.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
17  18  BARTON CHAPEL   2.5 PENASCAL I  3.0
18  19  BARTON CHAPEL   2.5 PENASCAL I  3.0
19  20  BARTON CHAPEL   2.5 PENASCAL I  3.0
20  21  BARTON CHAPEL   2.5 PENASCAL I  3.0
21  22  BARTON CHAPEL   2.5 PENASCAL I  3.0
22  23  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.0
23  24  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.0
24  25  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.0
25  26  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.0
26  27  BARTON CHAPEL   1.8 PENASCAL I  1.0
27  28  BARTON CHAPEL   1.8 PENASCAL I  1.0
28  29  BARTON CHAPEL   1.8 PENASCAL I  1.0
29  30  BARTON CHAPEL   1.8 PENASCAL I  1.0
30  31  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.2
31  32  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.2
32  33  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.2
33  34  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.2
34  35  BARTON CHAPEL   1.5 PENASCAL I  1.2
35  36  BARTON CHAPEL   3.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
36  37  BARTON CHAPEL   3.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
37  38  BARTON CHAPEL   3.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
38  39  BARTON CHAPEL   3.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
39  40  BARTON CHAPEL   2.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
40  41  BARTON CHAPEL   2.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
41  42  BARTON CHAPEL   2.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
42  43  BARTON CHAPEL   2.4 PENASCAL I  1.0
43  44  BARTON CHAPEL   1.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
44  45  BARTON CHAPEL   1.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
45  46  BARTON CHAPEL   1.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
46  47  BARTON CHAPEL   1.0 PENASCAL I  1.0
47  48  BARTON CHAPEL   1.6 PENASCAL I  1.0
48  49  BARTON CHAPEL   1.6 PENASCAL I  1.0
49  50  BARTON CHAPEL   1.6 PENASCAL I  1.0
50  51  BARTON CHAPEL   1.6 PENASCAL I  1.0
51  52  BARTON CHAPEL   1.6 PENASCAL I  1.0
```

I need to convert this df into a 8736 x 5 (week, SITE, LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL, SITE LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL) new dataframe such that each site has a column called 'SITE' and the data associated with it is in a column 'LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL' organized by hour. The data in the 'LGTNG ACTIVITY LEVEL' should = the data for each week. thank you! I've tried lots of solutions with repeat and tile but cannot get the final 8736 x 5 column df.

Comment: Trying `df.loc[df.index.repeat(3)]` in a much smaller example with duplicate column labels worked fine for me. Does it work for you with 168 repetitions? If not, could you clarify the problem you're running into?